# Windows Server edition mixing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am a linux person by trade, so this windows stuff confuses me.

I am going to setup a PDC and BDC, and I need another windows server license for a storage server.

I have a MAPS license which includes WinSrvr Standard 2008 (not R2), Enterprise R2. I have been quoted for a WinSrvr2008R2 OEM license with the new BDC.

Can I use, for example, Server 2008 R2 standard as the PDC, and Enterprise R2 as a BDC or vice versa, or do they have to be the same edition of windows?

The Storage Server can be 2008 Std (non-R2)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions yes you can do what you propose. I would however if possible swap to enterprise for your PDC but at the end of the day it shouldnt matter to much for you.

Comment: Thanks, yes I will take enterprise as the 'PDC' or as I understand it now I can use multimaster mode, so get the new server in and installed, add it to the domain , do some $voodoo, and drop the 2003 SBS box.

Comment: If you are migrating away from SBS you will need to make sure you switch on it's "Migration Mode" as running another server with any of the FSMO roles will cause SBS to shutdown randomly! Good Luck :)